# Formatting Textbox number on Leave event

Tags: c#, string, textbox, formatting, numbers

I know this is simple but need some help in formatting a number in a textbox on Leave event. I am trying the below but I am getting incorrect results.

This is what Im expecting:

100 = 100

1000 = 1,000

10000 = 10,000

10000.25 = 10,000.25

2500000.432 = 2,500,000.432

```
txtAmount.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID"), "{0:#,##0.##}", double.Parse(txtAmount.Text));
```

Comment: Wouldn't the standard number formatting rules work for you?, E.g., `string.Format("{0:N}", double.Parse(txtAmount.Text))`

Comment: @DiskJunky Im not really an expert, I found this online :/

Comment: Then I'd suggest having a read through the .NET documentation here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings